comments logged on console after onContextMenu trigger function in my react application appears for a split second and disappears
I've been facing this issue since a long time and can't get over it. I have a react application and I've set up onContextMenu which calls a function handleTableRightClick when triggered. Inside the function I've set up logs and other tasks to ececute. but when I see on my console of brave browser, the logs in the handleTableRightClick function appears for a split second and disappeares.
Here is my onContextMenu trigger (they are present for each row):
  <tr
   key={i}
   onContextMenu={(e) => handleTableRightClick(e, o, i)}
   >

Here is my handleTableRightCLick function:
 const handleTableRightClick = (e, rowData, i) => {
    e.stopPropagation();
    e.preventDefault();
    const contextMenuWidth = 200;

    const scrollX = window.pageXOffset || document.documentElement.scrollLeft;
    const scrollY = window.pageYOffset || document.documentElement.scrollTop;
    const xMultiplier = e.clientX > window.innerWidth / 1.5 ? -1 : 0;
    setMenuPosition({
      x: e.clientX + scrollX + contextMenuWidth * xMultiplier,
      y: e.clientY + scrollY,
    });

    setIsRightClickMenuOpen(true); // Open the right-click menu

    
  };

I've looked over default behaviour and propagation and added them but its still not working.

And where is that console.log call? I cannot see it in the block of handleTableRightClick, or anywhere here.
